# Win Loss Ratio based on Total Games lost and Total Bets

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to work out a mathematically a players Ratio of Win's Losses based on the players Total Games they lost and Total Bets placed?

For example:

```
Wins = 1
Loses = 111
Played = 112 
Total = 500
Won = 100 
Lost = 400
Percent = 0.8928571428571428
```

Win/Loss Ratio:

```
var wins = 1;
var loses = 111;
var percent = wins / (wins + loses) *100; //(1 / (1 + 111)*100)
//percent = 0.8928571428571428
```

What is the best way to factor in the "Total" amount spent and Total Games "Played" to get the best Ratio?

Ratio based on Total Spent and Lost:

```
var total = 500;
var lost = 400;
var loses = 111;
var ratio = lost / loses;
    ratio = ratio / total;
    //ratio = 0.032175032175032175;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you like `(won - lost) / total`? You get `+1` if you win everything, `-1` if you lose everything and `0` if you lose as much as you win.

Comment: @NicoSchertler thanks i will try that out and see how the results look. i wanted a result that is very different for each users score (so it would be easier to tell the difference between them when sorting). for instance none of the ratio's to match even if its a lower/higher by a decimal point minus/plus as you say.